# Bitcore multisig - how to sign a partially signed multisig bitcoin transaction

Tags: javascript, bitcoin

I am trying to figure out what is the correct way to sign a partially signed multisig bitcoin transaction using bitpay's opensource Bitcore library (http://bitcore.io)?

For multisig bitcoin transaction, one person may sign the transaction with his private key.  Pass that transaction to another person to sign using another private key.

If a bitcoin transaction is created using bitcore, we can use bitcore's TransactionBuilder to build the transaction and sign by calling sign().  However, if someone else has a transaction that is already signed by him and pass it to you to sign.  How should we use bitcore library to sign?  Is there a way to translate the transaction into bitcore TransactionBuilder object and call sign() method?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I suggest asking at bitcoin.stackexchange.com - more expertise there :)

Comment: can i switch this question to bitcoin.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry this is not bitcore specific but they way you explaining the series of events indicates you might be missing one detail of a multisig transactions.

For multisig all parties submit their public key to create the address.

A multisig address is then created.

Any coins sent to that address need n of m private keys to sign an agreed upon txn for the coin ownership to move in the blockchain.

Once a transaction is agreed upon all parties sign the transaction using their own public key but Bob does not need to pass on his signed transaction to Alice.  Bob and Alice simply need to agree that the multisig address will take an amount of its inputs and use those for outputs to another address.

To be clear there is no partially signed transaction from the users standpoint only the network clients verifying a transaction.  A partially signed txn is a txn submitted to the network that does not have all the signatures needed but all signed transactions can be submitted independently from one another.  The network will only authorize the multisig txn when there are sufficient signed txns by n different keys per the parameters that created the multisig address.

Bitcore Has an Example of Multsig [here](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore/blob/master/examples/CreateAndSignTx-Multisig.js)

Comment: I know that.  But my question is about how to do that with bitcore library.  Thanks for the response anyway.

Comment: https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore/blob/master/examples/CreateAndSignTx-Multisig.js